# Error in SQL when insert date in datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I've a problem in MySql when I try to insert in my database a date.

My table have a datetime column and, when I insert some values with PHP like

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2) VALUES ('1','2010-11-20');
```

[Column2 is a DATETIME]

My result, in my database is '1' and  '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and I don't know why because this worked.... :S.

What can be the problem?

Sorry...I explain more my problem

I read this values from a file with the format '20-11-2010' and I change to the MySql format (it is easy) and write my Insert sentence.

My Insert sentence is good, I put this in other file (like .log) and the result is:

```
INSERT INTO telephones (telephone,date) VALUES ('123456789','2014-18-11');
```

But if I look my database, the result is:

```
'123456789' and '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

**Edit:**

But in some cases, I've values like `'2010-11-20 16:30:20'`. If I change my DATETIME for DATE, I will lose this value.

My data value come from a File and the value is like

```
'123456789''20-11-2010 16:00:00' [First value is a telephon number and the next is the date]
```

But in some cases, I recive the date without the time.

When I reed the dates, I changed the value using explode() and I return the value in the next order

```
$myDate = $date[2]."-".$date[1]."-".$date[0];
```

When I construct my insert I try the @entiendoNull solution like

date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($myDate));

but this put in my insert sentence "1970-01-01 XX:xx:xx"

Comment: Are you getting an error? Where is the PHP that enters that into the DB? We need more to go on.

Comment: Could it be that you need to specify the time too..? if you just want the date set the column to be "date" instead of "datetime".

Comment: take for sure that your php $value is really '2010-11-20'

Comment: Yes, it's a correct type because sometimes I've the value date and time, for this reason, I need datetime in my database. My value in PHP is correct.

Comment: try inserting this: `$formattedDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($value));` _$value contains a date, for example 2015-01-19_

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert info in a DATE format into a column accepting DATETIME.

Concluding, you either have to change your column in your table to a "DATE", or (better) just insert 00:00:00 as time:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2) VALUES ('1','2010-11-20 00:00:00');
```

Comment: But in some cases, I've values like '2010-11-20 16:30:20'. If i change my DATETIME for DATE, I will lose this value

Comment: Your only option then is to insert zero's for the time. If you afterwards want to compare dates only, you should use the sql between operator: 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2 BETWEEN '2010-11-20 00:00:00' AND '2010-11-20 23:59:59'

Answer (score 0):

Format your date the following way and then try to insert it:

```
$formattedDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($value)); //$value holds a date e.g. 2015-01-19 or a datetime e.g. 2015-01-19 10:58:01
```